# Using multiple IR receivers on a raspberry pi with LIRC

Tags: gpio, pi-zero, lirc

I'm trying to create a DIY laser tag/game and I want each player to wear multiple targets, but I can't find a tutorial that explains how to use multiple IR receivers.
I just need to be able to know if there is any signal received by any receiver using a python script.
Can I just connect every receiver to a GPIO pin and then check all of them one after the other using a python library as it is made in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158282/script-to-read-multiple-raspberry-pi-input-pins) ?

Comment: Show us the working code to connect and check one sensor.  That will help us work out if multiple sensors are feasible.

Comment: `know if there is any signal received by any receiver ` ... connect the sensors in parallel to one GPIO pin

Comment: @juan I actually don't know which library I'm supposed to use. I also just realized that it might be interesting to have access to the receivers because I could use them to receiver signals when a player killed another player ( the dead player sends a IR signal received by the killer. This signal will be different from the signal of a shot and it will increase the kill counter of the player by one.

btw I know how to code in python

Comment: Basically you want to connect an unknown sensor using an unknown protocol.  No one can help with that.